# Function Running in local and not when deployed to Azure

Tags: azure-function-app, azure-http-trigger

I have a http trigger function, when I sent a message to the url, it logs data on the queuestorage as required;

```
http://localhost:7071/api/xxxx?message=89000
```

However when I do the same in azure on the function url

`https://yyyyy.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxx?message=89000` nothing is logged.

How can I have this resolved?

Another question;
The underlying code is

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
def main(req: func.HttpRequest,msg: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    input_msg = req.params.get('message')
    logging.info(input_msg)
    msg.set(input_msg)
    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This is a test.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

It is expected to receive the following payload

```
{
    "layerId":0,
    "serviceName": "myService",
    "changeType": "FeaturesCreated",
    "orgId": "myorgId"
    "changesUrl": "https://olserver/services/myService/FeatureService/extractChanges?serverGens=[1122, 1124]"
}
```

when I do  `http://localhost:7071/api/xxxx?message=89000`, it logs the queue storage just fine but not when this payload is delivered. How can I have this configured?

Comment: Any more problems? If not, maybe we can end this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure function app don't get environment variable from local.settings.json on portal.

You need to add below setting:

[image]

To

[image]

And in order to prevent the inability to save messages due to certain settings of the queue, you can try to create a new queue to avoid this situation.

Comment: On this one, if I wanted the app to log `message={
 "layerId":0,
 "serviceName": "myService",
 "changeType": "FeaturesUpdated",
 "orgId": "myorgId"
 "changesUrl": "https://olserver/services/myService/FeatureService/extractChanges?serverGens=[1122, 1124]"
}` instead of `message=20000` are there setting to tweak?

Comment: @wwnde I didn't read the underlying code of queue binding, but it is likely to be string based. You may be able to write it to queue like a normal string, and then use some modules to convert it when reading.

Comment: @wwnde You can write normally without problem, but it should have no nested structure

Comment: see my edits. Is there away to configure the code to expect the payload?

Comment: @wwnde I have something to do outside for the time being. I don't have a computer around me. I'll help you and do a test when I go back.

Comment: I can resolve this issue by logging a specific string every time the client http is triggered. How can I for instance change the code to ensure say a message 11111 is queued every time. I don't mind if that causes an overwrite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224612/discussion-between-wwnde-and-bowman-zhu).